# How to merge multiple XLSX files into one Workbook while keeping their worksheets separate?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to merge all .xlsx files within a folder into one workbook while keeping their worksheets separated. My code below is grabbing specified files, merging them into one workbook but only copying the first worksheet from each file instead of all their worksheets.

My output file is currently one workbook containing the first worksheet of each merged file but some files have multiple worksheets. Would anyone know how I can grab all worksheets from multiple files and combine them into one workbook?

Thanks for your time!

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\merge'
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Daily Pipeline"), os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Loans")]: 
    w = excel.Workbooks.Open(f) 
    w.Sheets(1).Copy(wb.Sheets(1))


wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Final.xlsx"))
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you try reading the excel files using python pandas? You could use glob to read the files from your directory and then merge them into a dataframe.

```
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
path = 'd:/projects/chassis/data/*.xlsx'
for f in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None, ignore_index=True, skiprows=6, usecols=8)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values())
    all_data = all_data.append(cdf,ignore_index=True)
print(all_data)
```

This might do the work!

Comment: Thank you for helping me look into this. Your code combined all of the workbooks into one workbook with one worksheet, I'm hoping to combine the workbooks together into one workbook while keeping their worksheet tabs separate.

Comment: @Nantourakis you can do that by simply replacing ```sheet_name=None``` to ```sheet_name=['a','b','c'...'nth']```.

Comment: by setting sheet_name=None, all sheets are by default selected. You can check this out for your understanding. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html